# Golang new template not working

Tags: templates, go

When I run:

```
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
t.Execute(w, nil)
```

the page loads fine.
But when I try and run

```
t := template.New("first")
t, _ = t.ParseFiles("index.html")
t.Execute(w, nil)
```

the only thing that loads is a blank page.
I am trying to change the delimiter values in a Golang html template and would like to make the template, change the delimiter values, then parse the file.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first version works as you expect because the package-level `ParseFiles` function will return a new template that has the name and content of the first parsed file.

In the second case, though, you're creating a template named `"first"` and then parsing one with name `"index.html"`. When you call `t.Execute` on `"first"`, it's still empty.

You can fix the problem by either:

1. Using `template.New("index.html")`, so that the file name matches the template name you parse next;
2. Providing the template name you want to execute explicitly with `t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)`